Python: init exception from another (like raise ... from but with no raise)
I am working on a piece of FastAPI app code that (already) has some exception handling, where handlers receive exceptions as function arguments, some exceptions are converted into other exceptions and then are passed on to other handler functions. My task is to log them, and I would like to be able to keep all the stactrace, including for those exceptions that resulted from converting other exceptions. However, when return MyNewException(old_exc.args) is called, all the stacktrace from the first exception is lost.
I know that you can append to the stactrace if you raise MyNewException(old_exc.args) from old_exc, but here there's no raising, only passing exceptions raised and caught elsewhere.
Is there a way I can incorporate the stacktrace from the original exceptions in my situation?

If you're not going to throw that exception, you probably shouldn't create it at all. If you want to log an exception, log the original exception.

It was caught somewhere else and passed in as a param. It is a web framework, so the exceptions have to be logged and a correspondind error code and response was sent back to the client

Turns out, you can just do:
e1 = MyOtherException(e.args).with_traceback(e.__traceback__)

